# Spectral projection and multiplicity of eigenvalues

Tags: functional-analysis

In Brain's book "quantum theory for mathematicians", let $A$ be a bounded  self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$, use the functional calculus form of the spectral theorem, one can define
$$ f(A)=\int_{\sigma(A)} f(\lambda) d\mu^{A}(\lambda) $$
for Borel measurable function $f$ on $\sigma(A)$.

So one can use this to define the spectral projection $P_{E}(A)$ for Borel set $E\subset \mathbb{R}$, and set $V_{E}=Range (P_{E}(A))$.

Note one can prove that $\lambda\in \sigma(A)$ if and only if $P_{(\lambda-\epsilon, \lambda+\epsilon)}(A)\neq 0$ for all $\epsilon>0$, and hence one can define the essential spectrum and the discrete spectrum. My question is that what is the relation between $dim V_{E}$ and the multiplicity of the "eigenvalue" $\lambda\in \sigma(A)$.

If we know $\lambda\in \sigma_{pp}(A)$, the point spectrum of $A$, then I think the dimension of the space $V_{E}$ is indeed the multiplicity of the eigenvalue $\lambda$, if we choose $\epsilon$ small enough.

But note if $\lambda$ is in the continuous spectrum, like if we consider the self-adjoint operator multiplication by $x$ on $L^{2}([0,1])$, the spectrum is equal to $[0,1]$, but all the spectral spaces are infinite dimensional.